# How to get data from Firebase and save into Google Sheet using Google App Script?

Tags: firebase, google-apps-script, fetch

First I made an app which send the data to Firebase. Now I want when data is saving on firebase then it will save on Google Sheet from firebase. I want to get the data from Firebase and save into Google Sheet using Google app script.

Comment: You haven't specified whether you are having trouble with the writing to sheet part, or what your current code is. Please do so if you'd like more clarification :)

Answer (score 2):

[Here's a tutorial.](https://sites.google.com/site/scriptsexamples/new-connectors-to-google-services/firebase/tutorials/read-and-write-data-in-firebase-from-apps-script) Scroll to the "Reading data from Firebase with different queries" section.

Here's a part of it:

> If you want to retrieve all data stored in Firebase, simply perform a
>   getData() with no path / location.
>
> ```
> function getAllData() {
>   var firebaseUrl = "https://script-examples.firebaseio.com/";
>   var base = FirebaseApp.getDatabaseByUrl(firebaseUrl);
>   var data = base.getData();
>   for(var i in data) {
>     Logger.log(data[i].firstName + ' ' + data[i].lastName);
>   }
> }
> ```
>
> To retrieve a specific record, simply indicate the right path / key.
>
> ```
> function getContact() {
>   var firebaseUrl = "https://script-examples.firebaseio.com/";
>   var base = FirebaseApp.getDatabaseByUrl(firebaseUrl);
>   var contact = base.getData("Alex-MARTIN");
>   Logger.log(contact);
> }
> ```
>
> Or directly get a specific the value (eg. Country for a specific
>   contact)
>
> ```
> function getContactCountry() {
>   var firebaseUrl = "https://script-examples.firebaseio.com/";
>   var base = FirebaseApp.getDatabaseByUrl(firebaseUrl);
>   var country = base.getData("Alex-MARTIN/country");
>   Logger.log(country);
> }
> ```